# Get STDOUT from Runtime.getRuntime().exec() line-by-line rather than all at once

Tags: java, process, inputstream, stdin, bufferedreader

I'm executing a script from Java with the following code.

```
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime()
            .exec("ruby test.rb").getInputStream()))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Got line: " + line);
        }
    }
```

Where `test.rb` is simply:

```
puts "one"
sleep 1
puts "two"
```

The problem is that all of the input arrives in the `BufferedReader` at the same time.  There should be a 1 second delay between the two lines. Is there a way to flush the `Inputstream` after every line in the script?

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I want to call some Ruby scripts from a Java GUI and have the output of the script show up incrementally in a textpane.  Using the code above, STDOUT from the script shows up in the textpane all at once when the script terminates (and the `Inputstream` is presumably flushed).

Edit:
The issue was that Ruby was buffering STDOUT. Fixed by `$stdout.sync = true`.

Comment: Add `$stdout.sync = true` to your ruby script.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That was it. Thank you so much. I knew it had to be something like this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Thread.sleep(1000) after System.out.println(). You must catch some InterruptedException. Your editor will tell you for sure.

Comment: The sleep for one second is just an example. I would actually have a task which takes some unknown amount of time instead.

Comment: Ok then: that's not possible. One Idea is to puts a delimiter in ruby, the Java inputstream is waiting for. But that won't be that easy. Remember it's just a stream in Java. This stream cannot know what's comming next, so you should give it some flags.